# Histogram and Normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, data-analysis

I was studying histograms and normal distribution. As far as I know, they are two different tools used for calculating probability and statistics. More specifically they help to visualize and it is an effective way to summarize a large amount of data.

The main difference is in their math and the way they visualize. To calculate the probability of an event from a histogram, we calculate it in a normal arithmetic way. But, if we want to calculate probability from normal distribution we need calculus and geometry.
I am adding screenshots so that everyone could understand what I meant above.
[image: Histogram]
[image: Normal distribution]

Could anyone help me to know their use cases? In which cases it will be better to use histograms and normal distribution? Is there any condition I should check before deciding which one I should use whether it is histogram or normal distribution?

Comment: The normal distribution is a specific distribution. Not all data follows this shape. Some may be exponential, Gamma, triangle, uniform... Histograms are great to look at general shape and frequency.

Comment: Histograms are often used to show data that have been collected for a population. Density curves, such as the one you show for the normal distribution may be used to answer questions about the population. I will show examples in my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Histogram of a small sample.**

Suppose you have a population of high school women, you sample 100
womn at random from the population, measure their heights (to the nearest inch) and make a histogram of these 100 heights.

Using R statistical software, I can emulate this process to get
fictitious data for an example. The vector `x` contains the heights in inches of 100 women.

```
 set.seed(2021)                  # for reproducibility
 x = round(rnorm(100, 64, 3.5))  # draw sample, round; see Note at end
```

From the following summary I can see that the
tallest woman was 71" tall and the shortest was 56" tall.
Also, I can see that that the average height is $\bar X = 63.36"$

```
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  56.00   61.00   63.50   63.36   66.00   71.00
```

The histogram below has labels atop its bars, indicating how many women are represented in each bar. So, I can say that $8+10+1 = 19$ of the $100$ women
are taller than 66". [In this style of histogram the intervals contain the top boundary, but not the bottom boundary.] From this I might guess that roughly $0.19 = 19\%$ of the women in the -population_ are
taller than 66". But this is only a rough estimate based on a sample of 100. Perhaps it is more appropriate to give a
95% confidence interval for the probability as $(0.113, 0.267)$
or $0.19 \pm 0.077.$

```
hist(x, col="skyblue2", label=T)

p.est = 0.19
CI = p.est + qnorm(c(.025,.975))*sqrt(p.est*(1-p.est)/100) 
CI
[1] 0.1131104 0.2668896
```

[image]

```
sum(x > 66)
[1] 19
```

**Exact distribution of population.**

By contrast, if I am told that the population distribution of such
female student heights is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 64, \sigma=3.5).$
then I have more knowledge about the population than I can deduce
form a sample of $100$ women.

Then I can find a z-score and use printed normal CDF tables to
find the exact proportion of high school women in the population
weighing more than 66". For the best result, I should use $66.5$ because women taller than that will be rounded to 67" or more. (This adjustment is called the 'continuity correction'.)

Then $Z = \frac{66.5 - 64}{3.5} = 0.714.$ And from the printed table you get approximately the proportion $0.238.$ [Usually, using printed tables involves some rounding, with a small loss of accuracy.]  You can
use the normal CDF function `pnorm` in R, to get the slightly
more accurate value $0.2376.$

```
z = (66.5-64)/3.5;  z
[1] 0.7142857
1 - pnorm(0.714)
[1] 0.2376136
1 - pnorm(66.5, 64, 3.5)
[1] 0.2375253
```

Of course, the answer $0.238$ from the exact population distribution
is much better than the approximate answer $0.19\pm 0.077$ estimated from
a sample of only 100 women. But you try to do your best with the information you have.

The probability $0.238$ is the area under the density curve to the right of the vertical line.

```
hdr = "Density of NORM(64, 3.5)"
curve(dnorm(x, 64, 3.5), 50, 75, lwd=2, ylab="Density", main=hdr)
 abline(h = 0, col="green2");  abline(v = 66.5, lwd=2)
```

[image]

*Note:* The information in the line of R code

```
x = round(rnorm(100, 64, 3.5))
```

would *never* be known in a practical situation. This was used only to
make a fictitious sample of 100. [I don't happen have a huge population of high school women in my office to use for taking the sample.]